# Change Tab Style in ActionBar

Tags: android, tabs, android-styles

I'm trying to get my tabs to look like this:

[image: Tab Bar Style]

However, I don't have a clue where to start.

I am using a `ViewPager` and `SherlockActionBar` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter` to handle tab creation, among other things.

Is this impossible with a `ViewPager`? I've looked over the [`style`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) options and there isn't any way to affect the height of the tabs, have the tabs scroll, or a way to change the selection look.

Will I have to create custom drawables? If not, how can I get a full height selection color (in this case, the white on the gray) or change the height of the tab bar, like in the image I provided?

I would appreciate it if anyone reading this could please try and refrain from telling me that I haven't tried looking for the answer to this question, because I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out for a while now, but I still have not figured much out. If you had no intention of doing this, then thank you for being a reasonable person. I have just had too many comments telling me that I haven't tried hard enough, but I'm still new to Android and I don't even know the proper key words to google for these problems, so I appreciate any patience that I can be given with this.

Answer (score 0):

The TitlePageIndicator from the ViewPagerIndicator library (http://viewpagerindicator.com/) is probably what you're looking for.

You'd still need to tweak a few things to get that kind of a selector on the title.